# How to change the CSS of an HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

After reading some questions/answers about this subject I have tried to make it works for me but I can't.

The story line is that I have X elements (so it means no ID just class) and I want to change the background when I click in one.

So with JS I did:

```
'click .switch' (event) {
    event.toElement.closest("li").css('background-color','black');


    if(this.stateMachine == 'running'){
      Meteor.call("switch", this.nameMachine);
    }

  },
```

to get the container (here a `<li class="liMachine switch">`) but I have this error:

> event.toElement.closest(...).css is not a function

Despite the `event.toElement.closest` returns the right element:
[image]

So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Change `event.toElement` to `$(this)` or `$(event.target)`. Preferably the former

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nothing happens, no error but no changes

Comment: What element is `click` in your selector? That's not valid HTML, unless you're using some odd library you haven't mentioned

Comment: It's with MeteorJS @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: It works with `$(event.target)` !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Meteor, you may prefer this syntax:

```
"click .switch": function(event){
$(event.target).css("background-color", "black");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('.liContainer.switch').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: powderblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="liContainer switch">one</li>
  <li class="liContainer switch">two</li>
  <li class="liContainer switch">three</li>
</ul>
```

If `$(event.target)` works for you then the problem was of course that you did not pass a jQuery object. So you can not use jQuery functions on non jQuery object.

Comment: in the snippet it works but in my JS nothing happens (I putted some logs but nothing is displayed)